# Lua Compiling Error 'do' expected near '['

Tags: lua

I have a Lua file that I decompiled using unluac. When I try to recompile the files without any changes I get the following error:

> lua: main.lua:647: 'do' expected near '['

I really do not know the problem here, as the while do statement follows the correct format. 
The error is on line 647 as stated above.

Source is here:

[Full Pastebin Source](http://pastebin.com/7f0q3q8Y)

Comment: Please include the source code in the question itself, and not in a separate link.

Answer (score 1):

Expressions like `while {}[1] do` and `if {}[1].parentFolderName then` are invalid because of `{}[1]` reference. It needs to be `({})[1]`. It's probably a result of some sort of automated processing, but you should be able to fix it manually.

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for the response. I tried the edits via http://repl.it/ and still had the same problem.

Comment: Your decompiler must be broken anyway. This condition will never be true so you might as well remove the whole loop...